# Spring equivalent to EJB Singleton Session Bean's concurrency guarantees

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, concurrency

I'm in the process of converting a Java EE 6 application to Spring + non-EE Container (for example Jetty) and I'm looking for an alternative to Java EE's Singleton Session Bean (usually implemented by using the `@Singleton` annotation).

The *Singleton* aspect of it is easily handled by Spring. But the `@Singleton` annotation also implies concurrency guarantees: By default, all methods of a Singleton Session Bean are strictly serialized by a write-lock. (The behavior is can be changed by using the `@Lock`annotation.)

Is there any  (ideally drop-in) equivalent in Spring? The `@Lock` customization feature is not necessary, I'm just looking for a better alternative than manually synchronizing every method of every Singleton Session Bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no equivalent in Spring. I ended up using manual synchronization where necessary.